# How to change language from default to other language afer login for com_users login menu?

Tags: joomla

I am using com_users component for login in multi-language  Joomla (2.5) site having english as default language and danish as 2nd language. For that I am using language switcher module
It provides login form in both languages danish and English.
The Whole Site Works  properly in bothe languages
But After filling the name and password in danish language the site is change to English language.

Comment: where are you redirected after login? Do you have a translation for that page?

Comment: Danish Language Login Redirectes to the Same Page As English Lanugage

Answer (score 0):

Go to the specific module for Danish language which displays the login from and look for the option: **Login Redirection Page**.

Change from Default to the desired localized page.

Comment: Does It possible using com_users component